# How is Google using "Soften" add this effect to background images?

Tags: javascript, css, web, graphics

I stumbled across a blurring/softening effect that's being added to background images via CSS or Javascript. I'd like to replicate this effect on background images on my website, but when I look into the code on the Google My Business I cannot figure out how to duplicate this effect.

Any ideas on how to duplicate this?
[Blurred Image Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u0aR.jpg)

Comment: That is just a plain URL. the blurring might be happening on backend. But you can still achieve that using CSS on browser itself

Comment: Exactly, that is pass to the backend for browser compatibility, but you can do it with css using:         filter:blur(5px);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please search on Google first, or check existing questions on StackOverflow before posting new questions.